# is there a solution for Queueing collections with multiple model types is not supported

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

i am tring to do this to get all the user in my system : $this->agents = User::all();
but i am getting this error `Queueing collections with multiple model types is not supported.` There is other classes that extend from the user like consultant, customer i dont know if this is the raison
This is my code:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Tickets;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Ticket;
use App\Models\Reply;
use App\Models\Dept;
use App\Models\Topic;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class EditTicket extends Component
{
    public Ticket $ticket;

   
    public $message= '';
    public $deptName;
    public  $agents=[];
    protected $listeners = [
       
        'ticketUpdated' => '$refresh',
    ];

    public function mount(Ticket $ticket)
    {
      $this->ticket = $ticket;
      $this->deptName = $ticket->dept->name;
      
    
    }
    public function render()
    {   
        $this->agents = User::all();
        
        return view('livewire.tickets.edit-ticket',[ 'agents' => $this->agents]);

    }
```

Comment: *$this->agents* is a public variable that should already reach the view. Try not passing the *'agents'* to the view or instead changing *$this->agents* to a *protected* or temporary variable.

Comment: I did a test and although my observation is correct, I verified that providing the same data in two different ways is useless but does not cause the problem you are exposing. Anyway I think you are not showing us the part of the code that causes the problem

Comment: @Pippo there is a two classes that extend from the User class so i think when i put them in one table that cause a problem

Comment: Ok, but here I can't see that in your code. I see that  you are passing only User model

Answer (score 0):

This modification ensures that you're only working with the base User model instances in your $agents collection, addressing the "Queueing collections with multiple model types is not supported" issue.

```
public function render()
        {
            // Fetch only base User models
            $this->agents = User::where('user_type', 'user')->get();
    
            return view('livewire.tickets.edit-ticket', ['agents' => $this->agents]);
        }
```

Comment: i tried this and i am getting: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_type' in 'where clause'
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_type` = USER AND `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL

Comment: first, clear the cache before doing this refresh the migration file and check whether it works or not if now working then inside the render add filter example :-   function render()
    {
        // Fetch all users and filter only base User models
        $allUsers = User::all();
        $this->agents = $allUsers->filter(function ($user) {
            return !($user instanceof Consultant || $user instanceof Customer);
        });

        return view('livewire.tickets.edit-ticket', ['agents' => $this->agents]);
    } i hope it can help you. thanks :)

Comment: thank you for your response but me i need to get all type of users

Comment: column issues solved? try this :-  $this->agents = User::select('*')
            ->where('user_type', 'user') // adjust based on your actual column and values
            ->union(Consultant::select('*'))
            ->union(Customer::select('*'))
            ->get();

Comment: I really can't understand why is supposed that the *users* table contains an user type